# counting total number of words in a text file

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to print the total number of words in a text file and the total number of specific words in the file provided by the user.

I tested my code, but results output of single word,but i need only the overall word count of all the words in the file and also the overall wordcount of words provided by the user.

Code:

```
name = raw_input("Enter the query x ")
name1 = raw_input("Enter the query y ")
file=open("xmlfil.xml","r+")
wordcount={}
for word in file.read().split():
    if word not in wordcount:
        wordcount[word] = 1
    else:
        wordcount[word] += 1
for k,v in wordcount.items():
    print k, v

for name in file.read().split():
    if name not in wordcount:
        wordcount[name] = 1
    else:
        wordcount[name] += 1
for k,v in wordcount.items():
    print k, v

for name1 in file.read().split():
    if name1 not in wordcount:
        wordcount[name1] = 1
    else:
        wordcount[name1] += 1
for k,v in wordcount.items():
    print k, v
```

Comment: `for x in file.read().split(): count+=1`

Comment: @ForceBru or just `len(file.read().split())`?

Comment: Also OP, don't name things `file`. You'll cause no end of trouble with overriding builtin functions

Answer (score 3):

```
MyFile=open('test.txt','r')
words={}
count=0
given_words=['The','document','1']
for x in MyFile.read().split():
    count+=1
    if x in given_words:
        words.setdefault(x,0)
        words[str(x)]+=1    
MyFile.close()
print count, words
```

Sample output

> 17 {'1': 1, 'The': 1, 'document': 1}

Please do not name the variable to handle `open()` result `file` as then you'll overwrite the constructor function for the `file` type.

Comment: thank u,how can i take the counts of given words seperately in seperate variables?

Comment: @adsalila, why do you need separate variables? A dictionary is an organized storage type while variables are not. Just use `words['1']` to get number of 1's occurred in your text. Don't forget to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

You can get what you need easily via `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
with open('your_file', 'rb') as f:
    for ln in f:
        c.update(ln.split())

total = sum(c.values())
specific = c['your_specific_word']
```

Comment: could u also please add,for specific words,along with your code?

Comment: as I wrote at the last line, you can query `c`, just replace `your_specific_word` with whatever you are interested. If exists, you will get its count. Otherwise, it returns `0`.