# how can i count how many words there are in the .txt file

Tags: python

ok so i know how i can count how many words there are in a string(`o = len(x.split()) print(o)`)  but how do i count how many words there are in a .txt file?

btw my code looks like this:

```
p = open("einsteinsbiography", "r", encoding="utf8")
x = dict()
for line in p:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.lower()
    t = line.split(" ")
    for word in t:
        if word in x:
            x[word] = x[word] + 1
        else:
            x[word] = 1
for key in list(x.keys()):
    print(key, ":", x[key])
```

Comment: Is [this](https://pythonexamples.org/python-count-number-of-words-in-text-file/) an answer to your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [counting total number of words in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766796/counting-total-number-of-words-in-a-text-file)

Comment: Okay, so what happened when you tried to run the code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: You want to get a count for each word? {word1 = 10, word2 = 3, ...}

Comment: The line you supply in your description counts only the total number of words, but your code looks like it's building a separate count for each unique word. Those are, of course, two different things...

Comment: Apart from the fact that your word counting on a string is counting the total words and the file counting is counting ***each*** word - what is your question? I see a code, which by looking at it does what it seems to be supposed to do... What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Number of words in the text file

```
num_chars = sum(len(word) for word in open('names.txt').read().split())
print(num_chars)
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation that is more memory friendly (it iterates over the .txt file line-by-line, rather than loading it all at once):

```
with open("einsteinsbiography", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    total = 0
    for line in file:
        # Remove all kinds of trailing whitespace with rstrip method
        total += len((line.rstrip()).split(' '))
print(total)
```

If you want to count the number of instances of each word, I would recommend the answer by big_bad_bison and use a Counter object.

Answer (score -1):

To get just the total number of words in the file:

```
with open("einsteinsbiography", "r", encoding="utf8") as p:
    txt = p.read()
words = txt.split()
print(len(words))
```

If you want to get a dict with a count of each word in the file, use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

with open("einsteinsbiography", "r", encoding="utf8") as p:
    txt = p.read()
words = txt.split()
c = Counter(words)
print(c)
```

Comment: `txt.split(' ')` will split on only spaces, but not on newlines. I think you want `txt.split()`, which will split on all whitespace. This also groups consecutive whitespace characters together instead of adding empty entries to the list. [Link to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)